# how to select text by the current position of the caret?

Tags: javascript

“[Selection object represents the range of text selected by the user or the current position of the caret](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)” so how to select text by the current position of the caret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create range and add it to the selection, with use of [addRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange).

Code example:

```
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(0, currentPos);
  sel.addRange(range);
```